# Is every critically subsimple Laver-like algebra a quotient of a critically simple Laver-like algebra on the same number of generators?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals, self-distributivity

A finite reduced Laver-like algebra is a finite algebra $(X,*,1)$ that satisfies the identities $1*x=x,x*1=1,x*(y*z)=(x*y)*(x*z)$ and where there is a natural number $n$ and a function $\mathrm{crit}:X\rightarrow n+1$ where

1. $\mathrm{crit}(x)=n$ if and only if $x=1$,
2. $\mathrm{crit}(x*y)=\mathrm{crit}(y)$ whenever $\mathrm{crit}(y)<\mathrm{crit}(x)$, and
3. $\mathrm{crit}(x*y)>\mathrm{crit}(y)$ whenever
   $\mathrm{crit}(x)\leq\mathrm{crit}(y)<n$.

We say that a finite reduced Laver-like algebra $(X,*,1)$ is critically simple if whenever $\simeq$ is a congruence on $(X,*,1)$ where there are $x,y\in X$ with $x\simeq y,x\neq y$, there is some $z\in X\setminus\{1\}$ with $z\simeq 1$.

We say that $(X,*,1)$ is critically subsimple if $x,y\in X,x*x=1,y*y=1,\mathrm{crit}(x)=\mathrm{crit}(y)$ implies that $x=y$ for each $x,y\in X$. Every critically simple finite reduced Laver-like algebra is critically subsimple.

Suppose that $(X,*,1)$ is a critically subsimple finite reduced Laver-like algebra generated by $(x_{a})_{a\in A}$ where $A$ is finite. Then does there exist a critically simple finite reduced Laver-like algebra $(Y,*,1)$ generated by $(y_{a})_{a\in A}$ along with a homomorphism $\phi:Y\rightarrow X$ such that $\phi(y_{a})=x_{a}$ for each $a\in A$ and an element $c\in Y$ such that if $y_{1},y_{2}\in Y$, then $\phi(y_{1})=\phi(y_{2})$ if and only if $c*y_{1}=c*y_{2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A critically subsimple Laver-like algebra is not necessarily a quotient of a critically simple Laver-like algebra with the same number of generators and more critical points. Our strategy for producing counterexamples is to exhibit finite reduced Laver-like algebras $X$ generated by $(x_a)_{a\in A}$ such that there does not exist a finite reduced Laver-like algebra $Y$ generated by $(y_a)_{a\in A}$ such that $Y$ has more critical points than $X$ and such that there is a homomorphism $\phi:Y\rightarrow X$ with $\phi(y_a)=x_a$ for $a\in A$.

Given a finite reduced Laver-like algebra $X$ and a generating set $(x_a)_{a\in A}$, I have obtained an algorithm for finding the class $\text{Cov}(X,(x_a)_{a\in A})$ of all finite reduced Laver-like algebras $Y$ together with a generating set $(y_a)_{a\in A}$ such that $Y$ has $1$ more critical point than $X$ and where there is a homomorphism $\phi:Y\rightarrow X$ with $\phi(y_a)=x_a$ for $a\in A$.

Producing finite reduced Laver-like algebras where $\text{Cov}(X,(x_a)_{a\in A})=\emptyset$ is not trivial since examples of algebras $(X,(x_a)_{a\in A})$ with $\text{Cov}(X,(x_a)_{a\in A})=\emptyset$ are difficult to obtain, and I have not been able to obtain any algebras $(X,(x_a)_{a\in A})$ with $\text{Cov}(X,(x_a)_{a\in A})=\emptyset$ without explicitly looking for such an algebra. I only know of one way of constructing such an algebra.

The way I constructed an algebra was to first perform a brute force search for a small reduced Laver-like algebra $(X,*)$ generated by two elements $x,y$ with $y*y=1$ and where if $\phi:Y\rightarrow X$ is a homomorphism between two Laver-like algebras and $Y$ is generated by $a,b$ and $\phi(a)=x,\phi(b)=y$, then $Y,X$ both have the same number of critical points. After, we have obtained the minimal Laver-like algebra $(X,*)$, we produce a sequence $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ where $X_1=(X,(x,y))$, and $X_{j+1}\in\text{Cov}(X_j)$ for $1\leq j<n$, and where $\text{Cov}(X_j)=\emptyset$. If say that two finite Laver-like algebras $X,Y$ are critically equivalent if there are congruences both denoted by $\simeq$ on $X,Y$ where $X/\simeq$ is isomorphic to $Y/\simeq$ and where $X,Y,X/\simeq,Y/\simeq$ all have the same number of critical points. We find some $Z$ that is critically equivalent to $X_n$ but which is not critically subsimple and then $Z$ is our desired counterexample.